# Realistic GPS sensor as a Unity Game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gps, sensors

I'm trying to build a Global Positioning System sensor script(not the one that uses the real life Global Positioning System sensor), and use it as a game object. I'm trying to implement this sensor in a self driving car project. I have tried writing my own script which converts the x, y, z coordinates into longitude and latitude, What i would like to understand is just like building a radar sensor and light detection and ranging sensor and Inertial measurement unit sensor, how can i build a Global Positioning System sensor which gives us coordinates which accurately measures the position of one game object with respect to another game object withing the scene(world).

this is the script i have tried to build

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
//using System.Math;
//using System.Diagnostics;


public class GPS02 : MonoBehaviour {

       public float latitude;
       public float longitude;
       public double earthradius;

       public double Lat_lon;

       public float lat;
       public float lon;


       public static double enu2ecefx;
       public static double enu2ecefy;
       public static double enu2ecefz;

       public static float finalX;
       public static float finalY;
       public static float finalZ;

       const double a = 6378137f;         // WGS-84 Earth semimajor axis (m)

       const double b = 6356752f;     // Derived Earth semiminor axis (m)
       const double f = (a - b) / a;           // Ellipsoid Flatness
       const double f_inv = 1.0f / f; 
       const double a_sq = a * a;
       const double b_sq = b * b;
       const double e_sq = f * (2f - f);


      public GameObject carvar;

      public Car othervar;

      public double E;
      public double N;
      public double U;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
         othervar = carvar.GetComponent<Car>();
         E = othervar.east;
         N = othervar.north;
         U = othervar.up;       
         transform.position = Quaternion.AngleAxis(longitude, -Vector3.up) * Quaternion.AngleAxis(latitude, -Vector3.right) * new Vector3(0,0,1);  // ----not sure
        Debug.Log("X ECEF "+transform.position.z);
        Debug.Log("Y ECEF "+transform.position.x);
        Debug.Log("Z ECEF "+transform.position.y);

        EnuToEcef(E,N,U,latitude,longitude,earthradius,out enu2ecefx,out enu2ecefy,out enu2ecefz);

       finalX = transform.position.z + (float)enu2ecefx;
       finalY = transform.position.x + (float)enu2ecefy;
       finalZ = transform.position.y + (float)enu2ecefz;

        Debug.Log("final X "+finalX);
        Debug.Log("final Y "+finalY);
        Debug.Log("final Z "+finalZ);

        lat = (float)Math.Acos( finalY / earthradius);
        lon = (float)Math.Atan(finalX/ earthradius); 

        Debug.Log("lattitude "+lat);
        Debug.Log("lattitude "+lon);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }


    public  static void EnuToEcef(double E, double N, double U,
                                double latitude, double longitude, double earthradius,
                                out double enu2ecefx, out double enu2ecefy, out double enu2ecefz)
    {
        // Convert to radians in notation consistent with the paper:
        var lambda = DegreeToRadians(latitude);
        var phi = DegreeToRadians(longitude);
        var s = Math.Sin(lambda);
        var n = a / Math.Sqrt(1 - e_sq * s * s);

        var sin_lambda = Math.Sin(lambda);
        var cos_lambda = Math.Cos(lambda);
        var cos_phi = Math.Cos(phi);
        var sin_phi = Math.Sin(phi);

        double x0 =(earthradius + n) * cos_lambda * cos_phi;
        double y0 = (earthradius + n) * cos_lambda * sin_phi;
        double z0 = (earthradius + (1 - e_sq) * n) * sin_lambda;

        double xd = -sin_phi * E - cos_phi * sin_lambda * N+ cos_lambda * cos_phi * U;
        double yd = cos_phi * E - sin_lambda * sin_phi * N + cos_lambda * sin_phi * U;
        double zd = cos_lambda * N + sin_lambda * U;

        enu2ecefx = xd + x0;
        enu2ecefy = yd + y0;
        enu2ecefz = zd + z0;

        Debug.Log("car_x ECEF "+enu2ecefx);
        Debug.Log("car_y ECEF "+enu2ecefy);
        Debug.Log("car_z ECEF "+enu2ecefz);
    }

    public static double DegreeToRadians(double Lat_lon)
    {
        return (3.14f/180f)*Lat_lon;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you just compare one object's position to another's? If you want realism, choose between different radii (signal strength) and then occasionally move the position in that circle to simulate the inaccuracy of GPS.

Comment: thank you for reply. I'm getting coordinate of one object with respect to another. But i want to convert unity world coordinates into ECEF coordinates.

Comment: Oh. Is your terrain planetary?

Answer (score 3):

I think that what you want is to convert **cartesian coordinates (x, y, z)** to **geometric coord coordinates (radius, latitude, longitude)**.

Geometric coords are almost similar to **Spheric coord (radius, polar, azimuthal)**.

This [link](https://vvvv.org/blog/polar-spherical-and-geographic-coordinates#geographic-coordinates) shows the difference. The **latitude** angle is almost like the **polar** angle in spherical coord (90 - polar). The **longitude** is the **azimuthal** angle.

This gives us the following formulas:

**Cartesian to Geometric Coord**

- `radius = sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)`
- `latitude = arcsin(z/radius)`
- `longitude = atan2(y, x)`

And in case someone else needs it:

**Cartesian to Spherical Coord**

- `radius = sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)`
- `polar = arccos(z/radius)`
- `azimuthal = atan2(y, x)`

**Spherical to Geometric coord**

- `latitude = polar - 90°`
- `longitude = azimuthal`